# Show/hide drop down when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to Javascript. I have a program I am writing for a class which has a form. I need a drop down menu to appear with the months of the year in it if one of the two radio buttons is clicked. I have tried several different ways but I can't seem to figure it out. Also, I will need to do this for like 6 of the fields. So will I need more than one function or can I use the same one?

Comment: This is my HTML code.. well a small piece of the form. I don't know what to do with the Javascript

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeDropdowns(value){
    if(value=="radiobuttonYes"){
        document.getElementById('ddlId').style.display='none';
    }else if(value=="radiobuttonNo"){
        document.getElementById('ddlId').style.display='block';
    }
}
</script>
```

If all the fields depend on the same radio button value, you can use the same function by passing the clientId as parameter and using it in getElementById.

Comment: The form is a medical type form. It ask if you have had various shots and things like that. If you have had them, then I need to know when, which is what the dropdown is for. There will be a drop down for every one. I'm some-what confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an id to each element you'd like to show/hide then you can use JavaScript and CSS to show or hide those elements of the page.

Put this code in your header of the HTML file. Note that display affects layout, essentially removing the space the element takes up on the page. Visibility preserves layout, hiding the element but keeping it's space available. You can use whichever function suits you.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setVisible(id, visible) {
    var o = document.getElementById(id); //get the element based on it's id

    //if the element exists then set it's visiblity
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') o.style.visibility = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    if (typeof(o) == 'undefined') alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
}

function setDisplay(id, visible) {
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') o.style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
    if (typeof(o) == 'undefined') alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
}

</script>
```

Here is an example of what should be in the body. You can choose to use the setVisible or setDisplay function. Also, you may want to consider adding other even listeners to the radio buttons such as onchange because the user doesn't need to mouse click a radio button to check it. They can use the keyboard to select it as well which would not fire the onclick event.

```
<div>
    Radio:
    <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='first' onclick="setVisible('Div1', true); setVisible('Div2', false);" />
    <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='second' onclick="setVisible('Div2', true); setVisible('Div1', false);" />
</div>

<div id='Div1'>
    More form fields here.
</div>

<div id='Div2'>
    More form fields here.
</div>
```

Here is my full code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function setVisible(id, visible) {
        var o = document.getElementById(id);
        if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') o.style.visibility = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        if (typeof(o) == 'undefined') alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
    }

    function setDisplay(id, visible) {
        var o = document.getElementById(id);
        if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') o.style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
        if (typeof(o) == 'undefined') alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        Radio:
        <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='first' onclick="setVisible('Div1', true); setVisible('Div2', false);" />
        <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='second' onclick="setVisible('Div2', true); setVisible('Div1', false);" />
    </div>

    <div id='Div1'>
        More form fields here. 1
    </div>

    <div id='Div2'>
        More form fields here. 2
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put that in and it doesnt work. I can just click on the radio buttons, but absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: It could be that you are using the wrong identifier to change the visibility or display of an element. I've added some code to my examples to tell you if that is the case. Also, I've added my full code example. You can paste the full code into a webpage, view it in the browser, and it will run (assuming you have JavaScript enabled).

Comment: Your code does run. I need to do that more than once, but with different fields. Can i use the same function or will i have to make a new function for every one?

Comment: You can use the same function, just change the name of the ID to show or hide.

Comment: what do you mean by that? like how do i do that?

Comment: Notice in the full code example that there are two div tags with specified IDs: <div id='Div1'> and <div id='Div2'>. To show or hide one, refer to it's ID and call the function setVisible(id-of-div, true-or-false-visibility.) You'll probably want to call the function when an event fires, like the onclick event attached to each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they beat me to it. But, here's another example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>radio example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .show { display: block;  }
            .hide { display: none; }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showSelect() {
                var select = document.getElementById('my_select');
                select.className = 'show';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <label for="my_radio">Click me</label>
            <input id="my_radio" type="radio" name="options" value="some_value" onclick="showSelect();" />

            <select id="my_select" class="hide">
                <option value="someValue">Some Text</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```