# Java Script Hidden Function

Tags: javascript, html

Good day All,

I'm working on a fun little side project, for me, to teach myself JavaScript and to address my love of old cheesy sci-fi flicks (Village of the Gods, Them!, Tarantula, Attack of the 50 ft Woman, the Incredible Shrinking Man, Fantastic Voyage, Eight Legged Freaks). I wanted to make a program that would let you put in some basic stats and then hit a button to show what said person would in theory be proportionally on that scale.

That said I'm still mocking up the project and wanted to get some basic functionality out of the way. I want to put in an option that on a radio button toggle a text/select field will be either visible or invisible. I'm completely stumped on how to hide the field on a radio button click. I know I need the JavaScript in the header to govern a function to hide a field. I'm also toying with that entire table row vanishing and reappearing as needed.

I've looked at [Show/hide drop down when radio button is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847745/show-hide-drop-down-when-radio-button-is-selected][1]). And I understand what the header is doing, but I'm not sure how to implement it to my section, hair in this practicular case. Is there a better means of attempting to hide a value for a first time coder? And thank you in advance for any and all help.

--Edit--
Thank everyone for the help, I was unable to edit the code at work, I've updated with the solution I used so that the Div's will be included in the code. Sorry about forgetting those earlier.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Size Converter</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setVisible(id, visible) {
var o = document.getElementById(id); //get the element based on it's id

//if the element exists then set it's visiblity
if (isElement(o)) {
    o.style.visibility = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
} else {
    alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
}
}
function setDisplay(id, visible) {
var o = document.getElementById(id);
if (isElement(o)) {
    o.style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
} else {
    alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
}
}
function isElement(obj) {
var returnValue = false;
if (obj == undefined || obj == null) {
    returnValue = false;
} else {
    returnValue = true;
}
return returnValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<style>
BODY {
background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
#Subject, #CG {
border: solid 1px #000000;
padding: 2px;
}
</style>
<br>
<h1><center>Pre Transformation</center></h1>
<center><form>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%">
            <h3>
                Subject</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50%">
            <h3>
                Control Group</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div>
        Sex: <input type='radio' name='subjectsex' value='male' onclick="setVisible('Subject', false);" />Male
             <input type='radio' name='subjectsex' value='female' onclick="setVisible('Subject', true);" />Female
        </div></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <div>
        Sex: <input type='radio' name='CGsex' value='male' onclick="setVisible('CG', false);" />Male
             <input type='radio' name='CGsex' value='female' onclick="setVisible('CG', true);" />Female
        </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Height:&nbsp;<input size="2" value="5" type="text" />&nbsp;Feet&nbsp;<input size="2" value="6" type="text" />Inches</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            Height:&nbsp;<input size="2" value="5" type="text" />&nbsp;Feet&nbsp;<input size="2" value="6" type="text" />Inches</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Weight:&nbsp;<input size="2" value="130" type="text" />&nbsp;pounds</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            Weight:&nbsp;<input size="2" value="130" type="text" />&nbsp;pounds</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Measurements:&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />&nbsp;bust/chest&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />&nbsp;hips&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />waist</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            Measurements:&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />&nbsp;bust/chest&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />&nbsp;hips&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />waist</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <div id="Subject">
            Hair Length:&nbsp;<select name="hair">
            <option value=".5">Short/Pixie</option>
            <option value="1.0">Medium/Shoulder</option>
            <option value="1.5"selected="selected">Mid Back</option>
            <option value="2.0" >Waist Length</option></select></div></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td><div id="CG">
            Hair Length:&nbsp;<select name="hair">
            <option value=".5">Short/Pixie</option>
            <option value="1.0">Medium/Shoulder</option>
            <option value="1.5"selected="selected">Mid Back</option>
            <option value="2.0" >Waist Length</option></select></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Leg Percent:&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" /></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            Leg Percent:&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<input size="2" type="text" />Feet&nbsp;<input size="2" type="text" />&nbsp;inches</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<input type="button" value="Transform!" /></p>

<hr>
<h1><center>Post Transformation</center></h1>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
<td style="width:50%">
            <h3>
                Subject</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50%">
            <h3>
                Control Group</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your included markup, you don't have any elements with an id `Div1` or `Div2`.  Where do these exist?

Comment: Sorry xDaevax, I thought I commented that section out. It looks like I deleted it. The DIV is supposed to be where the Hair Select statement is. I wanted to stop before I got to far along and figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things, first I cleaned up your JS a bit and encapsulated your null check in a method.  I also added the missing markup elements which I assume were omitted on accident from your OP.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gev4kwnf/5/

The JavaScript now looks like this:

```
function setVisible(id, visible) {
    var o = document.getElementById(id); //get the element based on it's id

    //if the element exists then set it's visiblity
    if (isElement(o)) {
        o.style.visibility = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    } else {
        alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
    }
}

function setDisplay(id, visible) {
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    if (isElement(o)) {
        o.style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else {
        alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
    }
}

function isElement(obj) {
    var returnValue = false;
    if (obj == undefined || obj == null) {
        returnValue = false;
    } else {
        returnValue = true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daevax. With your example I was able to realize what I did wrong. And I appreciate you cleaning up the code, it should help me with future JavaScript coding.
I wanted to keep this internal so I embedded the <Style> in a singular .HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for this, is jQuery on change function, you can listen the change event and see if checkbox is checked to make the action based on response

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#myelement").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#myelement").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: OP didn't specify JQuery. And I wouldn't say using JQuery is necessarily a best practice either.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost working, besides this major error: *There are no Div1 and Div2* to show.
See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjxzgxru/) here.

just added

```
   <div id="Div1">This is div 1 </div>
    <div id="Div2">This is div 2 </div>
```

to your code

Answer (score 0):

Event if you want to go libraryless, there are a lot of ways you can do this (assuming you do have elements with ids "Div1" and "Div2" somewhere).

Here's one. It demonstrates a "better" way than `getElementByID` to find DOM elements:

```
var subMale   = document.querySelector('input[name=subjectsex][value=male]'),
    subFemale = document.querySelector('input[name=subjectsex][value=female]'),
    cgMale    = document.querySelector('input[name=CGsex][value=male]'),
    chFemale  = document.querySelector('input[name=CGsex][value=female]'),
    maleDivChange = function() {
        setVisible('Div1', true); 
        setVisible('Div2', false);
    },
    femaleDivChange = function() {
        setVisible('Div1', false); 
        setVisible('Div2', true);
    };

subMale.addEventListener('click', maleDivChange);
subFemale.addEventListener('click', femaleDivChange);
cgMale.addEventListener('click', maleDivChange);
chFemale.addEventListener('click', femaleDivChange);
```

This will work in modern browsers, including IE9. If you want to go earlier than that, there's some additional work to do.

There are a fair number of problems with it (e.g., if `Div1` and `Div2` are actually shared between the subject and control groups, clicking on subject male, CG female, and then on subject male again will leave "Div1" visible and "Div2" invisible. Moreover, it's pretty brute-force, and doesn't scale. If it were something I were actually doing, I'd probably do the visibility change by adding and removing CSS classes from the "Div1" and "Div2" elements (which I would probably tag with some other CSS class for each of finding, which would also make the solution extensible if I found any other gender-linked fields.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gojpgrqo/) with the above code.

Comment: I will probably be mostly doing my coding in Notepad++ and testing it on IE8, when I'm coding at work or on Chrome at home because those are the browsers I traditionally use in my work environment.